# How to extract more than label text items in a single annotation using Google NLP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, automl, google-cloud-nl, google-natural-language

I have created dataset using Google NLP Entity extraction and I uploaded input data's(train, test, validation jsonl files) like NLP format that will be stored in google storage bucket.

**Sample Annotation:**

```
   {
    "annotations": [{
        "text_extraction": {
            "text_segment": {
                "end_offset": 10,
                "start_offset": 0
            }
        },
        "display_name": "Name"
    }],
    "text_snippet": {
        "content": "JJ's Pizza\n "
    }
} {
    "annotations": [{
        "text_extraction": {
            "text_segment": {
                "end_offset": 9,
                "start_offset": 0
            }
        },
        "display_name": "City"
    }],
    "text_snippet": {
        "content": "San Francisco\n "
    }
}
```

Here is the input text to predict the label as "Name", "City" and "State"

> Best J J's Pizza in San Francisco, CA

Result in the following screenshot,

[image: predict-data]

I expect the predicted results would be in the following,

> **Name** : JJ's Pizza 
>   **City** : San Francisco 
>   **State**: CA

Comment: Could you explain how you have trained the model. How many samples did you use in the training set?

Comment: @Kim Model is Google Auto-ml NLP. i have 150 samples(train, test, validation) in training set.,

Comment: Is it returning only name? Or do you have also the labels City and State but without any value? Nevertheless, I guess 150 samples is too little to train any model. Try with more data and might change the result.

Comment: @IMB yes it's returning only name, because i put name as first label in the dataset, Those labels City and state has values

Comment: I would like just to understand what you really meant by the labels "City" and "State" had values! From the picture above we can see that just "Name" label that have a value of 1, and like the other labels have never existed.
I will really advise you to add more training data to your model, and more contents to your testing one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the sample annotation you provided, you're setting the whole `text_snippet` to be a `name` (or whatever field you want to extract).

This can confuse the model in understanding that *all the text* is that entity.

It would be better to have training data similar to the one in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare#entity-extraction). In there, there is a big chunk of text and then we annotate the entities that we want extracted from there.

---

As an example, let's say that from these text snippets I tell the model that the *cursive* part is an entity named `a`, while the **bold** part is an entity called `b`:

- *JJ Pizza*
- *LL Burritos*
- *Kebab MM*
- *Shushi NN*
- **San Francisco**
- **NY**
- **Washington**
- **Los Angeles**

Then, when then the model reads *Best JJ Pizza*, it thinks all is a single entity (we trained the model with this assumption), and it will just choose the one it matches the best (in this case, it would likely say it's an `a` entity).

However, if I provide the following text sample (also annotated like *cursive* is entity `a` and **bold** is entity `b`):

- The best pizza place in **San Francisco** is *JJ Pizza*.
- For a luxurious experience, do not forget to visit *LL Burritos* when you're around **NY**.
- I once visited *Kebab MM*, but there are better options in **Washington**.
- You can find *Shushi NN* in **Los Angles**

You can see how you're training the model to find the entities within a piece of text, and it will try to extract them according to the context.

---

The important part about training the model is providing training data as similar to real-life data as possible.

In the example you provided, if the data in your real-life scenario is going to be in the format `<ADJECTIVE> <NAME> <CITY>`, then your training data should have that same format:

```
{
    "annotations": [{
        "text_extraction": {
            "text_segment": {
                "end_offset": 16,
                "start_offset": 6
            }
        },
        "display_name": "Name"
    },
    {
        "text_extraction": {
            "text_segment": {
                "end_offset": 30,
                "start_offset": 21
            }
        },
        "display_name": "City"
    }],
    "text_snippet": {
        "content": "Worst JJ's Pizza in San Francisco\n "
    }
}
```

---

Note that the point of a Natural Language ML model is to process *natural language*. If your inputs are going to look as similar/simple/short as that, then it might not be worth going the ML route. A simple regex should be enough. Without the *natural language* part, it is going to be hard to properly train a model. More details in [the beginners guide](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/beginners-guide).